# Zend_Mail with french characters in mail body

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding, zend-mail

I'm trying to send a mail using `Zend_Mail` using the following code:

```
 function sendMail() {

     $config = array('auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'UserName',
                'password' => 'Password',
                'port'=>'27');    

    $mail = new Zend_Mail(); 

    $mail->setBodyText($mailBody);

    $mail->setFrom('example@host.com', 'The Company Name');
    $mail->addTo('example@host.com', 'Recipient Name');
    $mail->setSubject('Mail subject');    
    $mail->send(new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('example@server.com', $config));
}
```

Now the problem is that `$mailBody` has french characters. for example:

```
Merci d'avoir passé commande avec Lovre. Voici le récapitulatif de votre commande
```

When the sent mail is then viewed the same line appears like this:

```
Merci d'avoir pass? commande avec Lovre. Voici le r?capitulatif de votre commande
```

The accents were replaced by a question mark! I tried to encode the mail body using `utf8_encode`, but the problem still persisted.

Note: The body contents are read from a text file using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Did you ensure the text file has the right encoding? You can check it in a text editor. Doing that and constructing `Zend_Mail` with the `UTF-8` option (as suggested below) should be enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to set the encoding to UTF-8 in Zend_Mail constructor :

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
```

Make sure also that $mailBody contains UTF-8 text.

Comment: is there any way to set 'UTF-8' in the global $config?
Like this:
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport(new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config));

Answer (score 1):

Use the :

```
$mail->setBodyHtml();
```

instead of :

```
$mail->setBodyText();
```

the problem will be short out.

Comment: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3154/sending-non-english-character-emails/ check this link.